# How to find the inner SP's taking time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 1 main procedure and inside 5 procedure calls and my Main SP taking too much time. I want to find out which is the procedure call taking time to execute amongst inside 5 procedures.

Comment: run them individually for a starting point?...

Comment: You might find this question I asked on [dba.se] useful: [Can I get SSMS to show me the Actual query costs in the Execution plan pane?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24617/)

Comment: Try adding a PRINT statement spitting out the date/time after each of the sp's, and then run the code in the "master" sp from within SSMS? That way you can see how long each of the ther sps take to complete.

Comment: SQL Profiler can show you the execution time of all SQL statements, including individual statements within a stored procedure

Comment: @Pondlife, agreed but profiler is also using this DMO's.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, what does "using this DMOs" mean? SQL Profiler is specifically intended to be using for tracing execution time (among other things), so it isn't clear why you aren't using it.

Comment: @Pondlife, DMO Stands for Dynamic Management Objects, i mean to say like the profiler is using DMO objects at backhand to the code. SQL Profiler can degrade performance of your server(server means where the Production DB).

Comment: @MitchWheat, you are right but as Business doesn't allow us to run them individually.

Comment: @AakashM, yes right but it is for the Query, i have to implement it for the SP's and their sub SP's

Comment: There's more detail on reducing the performance impact of SQL Profiler [on the DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/818/using-sql-profiler-on-a-database-thats-in-production). But it's the right tool for the job and resolving your problem as quickly and efficiently as possible is the best way to reduce the impact on everyone.

Comment: @user569711 - `PRINT` is buffered - if there's no other output being produced, you may see no output until the *entire* process has run (e.g. `print 'ABC';WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30';print 'DEF'` takes 30 seconds to run, and you don't see `ABC` until those 30 seconds are up). If you do want to do this type of messaging, you should use `RAISERROR (<message>,10,1) WITH NOWAIT` which avoids buffering issues.

Comment: Don't use the profiler unless you REALLY have to. In my opinion you have no use for this tool, since it is also a very performance impacting tool. Look at my answer, how to find your query plan, and look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the query plan functionality for this. I wrote a blog post for this on http://plixa.nl/how-to-read-query-execution-plans/ where you can find out how to get the plan and how to read it

Answer (score 1):

You can log the strat time and end time of each proc in a separate table and then you can check which is taking long time.